# set minimum width of a div having position as relative

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to style this div both with a **min-width** and **width**

**css**

```
#diva {
   position: relative;
   margin: 0 auto;
   min-width: 75px;
   width: auto;
   height: 50px;
   padding: 4px;
   color: white;
   background-color: red;
}
```

**html**

```
<div id="diva">
    hello
</div>
```

When i set **width** to **auto**, this div occupies the full page width.

Comment: great , that is the effect of our comment ;)

Comment: don't know y people thumb down all my questions :(
question has got -1

Comment: This site gets very hostile ;) Don't worry yourself about it lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
display:inline-block;
```

Just add display:inline-block; to the styles for the div. That should work :)

http://jsfiddle.net/432kxywu/

Comment: it worked, but Stackoverflow says u cannot mark answer as correct for first 10 mins :D